# Paragraph parsing with perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, multiline

I have a large amount of Pdfs.  These are publications generated monthly and I would like to automate the ripping down and parsing of these documents to obtain contact info
to be imported into a DB.

Say there is a START and END tag to each block of text.  I need to Grab the "Comapny" after the start tag skip the "(Parantheses)" and PARAgraph in between then scrape
the PARTNER_COMPANY, "Title", and various forms of contact information until the END TAG then on the next.
The strings of contact info may vary however.  Some may have additional information than others, but I still need it in a uniform format that follows a specific header.
For variants, state,country, and zip may be on the same line delimited by ,.  Other variants of this may be delimted by \n.
When the program reaches the "Dated" section of the files, dates need to be parsed to a certain format(see below).
Some blocks of text will provide all of this contact info, others will not.  I want to parse until the END tag.

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
START

Company_1_ANY type of character

(Parantheses) 

PARAgraph

DATE: Dated this 5 day of NOvermber 2014 - parse date to yyyy-mm-dd format(2014-11-05)


PARTNER_COMPANY_1

Title - title_1

Contact for enquiries:  - CONTACT PERSON

HOMER Simpson

Telephone: (123) 123-1234 

FAX: (111) 346-0000 

Address: 

P.O. Box 123454, ANYTown, 12345-1234

STATE, USA

END



START

COMPANY_2_ANY type of character

(Parantheses)  


PARAGRAPH of random text

Dated this 5 day of November 2014 - 2014-11-05

PARTNER_COMPANY_2

Title - Title_2






address: 

190 RAndom Avenue, Any town

STATE_2 12345-0987

Country - USA

Contact: 

JOsh E

Telephone: (234) 111-1111

END
```

**CODE**

```
my @name;

while (<>) {
  if (/START/gism) {
    while (<>) {
      last if /END/;
      chomp;
      push @name, $_;

    }
    print "\t@name\n";
    @name = ()
  }
  else {
    print '';
  }
}
```

**MY RESULTS**

```
Company_1_ANY type of character  (Parantheses)   PARAgraph  DATE: Dated this 5 day of NOvermber 2014 - parse date to yyyy-mm-dd format(2014-11-05)   PARTNER_COMPANY_1  Title - title_1  Contact for enquiries:  - CONTACT PERSON  HOMER Simpson  Telephone: (123) 123-1234   FAX: (111) 346-0000   Address:   P.O. Box 123454, ANYTown, 12345-1234  STATE, USA 
COMPANY_2_ANY type of character  (Parantheses)     PARAGRAPH of random text  Dated this 5 day of November 2014 - 2014-11-05  PARTNER_COMPANY_2  Title - Title_2         address:   190 RAndom Avenue, Any town  STATE_2 12345-0987  Country - USA  Contact:   JOsh E  Telephone: (234) 111-1111
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
Company,DATE,PARTNER_COMPANY,Title,CONTACT PERSON,Telephone,FAX,Address,City,STATE,ZIP,Country

Company_1,2014-11-05,PARTNER_COMPANY_1,title_1,HOMER Simpson,(123) 123-1234,(111) 346-0000,P.O. Box 123454,ANYTown,12345-1234,USA

COMPANY_2,2014-11-05,PARTNER_COMPANY_2,Title_2,JOsh E,(234) 111-1111,,190 RAndom Avenue,Any town,STATE_2,12345-0987,USA
```

I am getting what I want between START and END but I am not sure how to delimit the elemtents in my array.  Also, I am not able to figure out how to filter out the unwanted, i.e. PARAGRAPH.  I would also like to trim what is in between delimiters.  I know a module may be useful in this, but for me to better understand how to create a hash and/or keys, is there a better way?

Also, in the DESIRED OUTPUT rows, disregard the line break given.  The row should continue delimited by commas.  This thread will only let the text be a certain length until the line breaks.

Comment: Thanks to format your sample input PROPERLY please, like your code !

Comment: Yes. The blank lines are real blank lines ? Not a bad formating input ?

Comment: Yes indeed there are blank lines, text in paragraph format and anything in between.  This is just a simplified sample.  @sputnick

Comment: Here is a technique I found useful http://blog.nu42.com/2014/09/scraping-pdf-documents-without-losing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this script as a base, it needs more work to fully fit your needs. It stores the informations in a Perl [Data Structure (DS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) : a HASH. The processing is done, you just need to iterate over the DS to produce the wanted output :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings; # always put this in your scripts
use Data::Dumper; # to print the data structure (DS) like in my OUTPUT section

my $h = []; # $h is a reference to a void ARRAY
my $witness1 = my $witness2 = 0; # setting the 2 variables with '0'
my $key = -1;

# using the magic 'diamond operator <>' to loop through the input file 
while (<DATA>) {
    next if /^$/; # skip this line if it's a blank line

    $key++ if /^START/; # iterating $key if the current line begins with 'START'

    # setting HASH values, $& is the matching part
    $h->[$key]->{Company} = $& if /^Company_.*/i;
    $h->[$key]->{Partner_Company} = $&  if /^PARTNER_COMPANY.*/i;
    $h->[$key]->{Title} = $& if /^TITLE\s+-\s+\K.*/i;

    # if there's 'CONTACT PERSON' string in the current line
    if (/CONTACT\s+PERSON/) {
        $witness1 = 1;
        next;
    }

    # witness1 tell us that we still are in the 'CONTACT PERSON' part
    if ($witness1) {
        $h->[$key]->{Name} = chomp($_);
        $witness1 = 0;
    }

    $h->[$key]->{Tel} = $& if /^Telephone: \K.*/i;
    $h->[$key]->{Fax} = $& if /^FAX: \K.*/i;

    if (/^Address:/i) {
        $witness2 = 1;
        next;
    }

    # witness2 tell us that we still are in the 'ADDRESS' part
    if ($witness2 and !/^END/) {
        $h->[$key]->{Address} .= $_;
    }

    if (/^END/) {
        $witness2 = 0;
    }
}

print Dumper $h;

__DATA__
START

Company_1_ANY type of character

(Parantheses) 

PARAgraph

DATE: Dated this 5 day of NOvermber 2014 - parse date to yyyy-mm-dd format(2014-11-05)


PARTNER_COMPANY_1

Title - title_1

Contact for enquiries:  - CONTACT PERSON

HOMER Simpson

Telephone: (123) 123-1234 

FAX: (111) 346-0000 

Address: 

P.O. Box 123454, ANYTown, 12345-1234

STATE, USA

END



START

COMPANY_2_ANY type of character

(Parantheses)  


PARAGRAPH of random text

Dated this 5 day of November 2014 - 2014-11-05

PARTNER_COMPANY_2

Title - Title_2






address: 

190 RAndom Avenue, Any town

STATE_2 12345-0987

Country - USA

Contact: 

JOsh E

Telephone: (234) 111-1111

END
```

Doc :

to understand references, I recommend you some pointers :

- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html

Comment: can you add comments on your code for me to better understand.  I am having a little trouble figuring this out.